# Qual o equivalente do mysql_result no mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Como posso fazer um `FOR` em php usando `mysqli`?

Pois eu sempre consegui fazer isso:

```
for($i=0; $i < $qtde; $i++){
   $pet_id = **mysql_result**($dadosPets, $i, 'animal_id');
}
```

Como eu faço o mesmo, porém, com `mysqli`?

Comment: Você pode pesquisar em sites do PHP sobre a documentação do mySQLi, pelo que saiba, mySQLi (my SQL improved) é uma versão aprimorada do SQL, então seus métodos e funções serão as mesmas, correto? Tente fazer isso com o mySQLi normal que deve funcionar.

Comment: Desculpe te informar @CypherPotato, mas isso não procede, pois já tentei e dá erro.
"Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/petsm976/public_html/php/default.php on line 164
"

Comment: @GustavoSevero mysql_* ou mysqli_*? Este Warning mostra mysql_*, E mysqli_result não existe nas funções mysqli_*,  veja pela qual ela foi substituída [neste link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)

Comment: @Coringa, eu estou usando mysql_, mas quero mudar para mysqli_

Comment: @Coringa, já olhei nesse link que vc indicou, mas não tem nenhum exemplo com FOR, todos são com WHILE.

Comment: GustavoSevero o link que o @coringa indicou está sim correto, veja que tem um trecho escrito `mysqli_data_seek() in conjunction with mysqli_field_seek() and mysqli_fetch_field()`, este é o exemplo correto, a função `data_seek`. Criei uma resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O próprio link da documentação pode lhe ajudar http://php.net/manual/en/ (recomendo em inglês, pois as vezes a versão em portugues contem erros :/ )

Terá que usar:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Um exemplo completo:

```
<?php
//Conecta
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Erro de conexão: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$query = 'SELECT ...'; //Sua select

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $qtde; $i++) {
        if ($result->data_seek($i)) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            //ID do pet
            $pet_id = $row['pet_id'];

        }
    }
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Estilo procedural:

```
<?php
//Conecta
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

if (!$link) {
    printf("Erro de conexão: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$query = 'SELECT ...'; //Sua select

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $qtde; $i++) {
        if (mysqli_data_seek($result, $i)) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            //ID do pet
            $pet_id = $row['pet_id'];
        }
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Vou tentar isso @GuilhermeNascimento, obrigado.

Comment: fui no link que vc passou, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php, e tentei usar o mesmo código, porém, procedural... Só não entendi como eu coloco o for... Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Valeu @GuilhermeNascimento, coloquei esse código procedural e apareceu a seguinte mensagem:
"Warning: mysqli_data_seek(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in /home/petsm976/public_html/php/default.php on line 167"

Comment: @GustavoSevero atualizei a resposta, veja que mudei duas linhas do código, teste de novo por favor.

Comment: Valeu @GuilhermeNscimento, nenhum erro aparece mais.
Só tento dar um echo na variável e ela não aparece hehehe

Comment: Sim, @GuilhermeNascimento, coloquei $pet_id = $row['pet_id'];, mas var_dump($data)? Que $data? hehehehe

Comment: Dei um var_dump($result), mas o resultado foi:

object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(14) ["lengths"]=> array(14) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(4) [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(1) [5]=> int(10) [6]=> int(1) [7]=> int(0) [8]=> int(1) [9]=> int(1) [10]=> int(1) [11]=> int(2) [12]=> int(12) [13]=> int(9) } ["num_rows"]=> int(4) ["type"]=> int(0) } object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(14) ["lengths"]=> array(14) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1)...

Comment: Dei um var_dump($row) e apareceu isso:

array(14) { [0]=> string(1) "9" [1]=> string(1) "5" [2]=> string(4) "Tuti" [3]=> string(1) "2" [4]=> string(1) "1" [5]=> string(10) "2013-06-11" [6]=> string(1) "2" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(1) "2" [9]=> string(1) "1" [10]=> string(1) "1" [11]=> string(2) "RS" [12]=> string(12) "Porto Alegre" [13]=> string(9) "cruza 50%" } array(14) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> ...

Cara, esse var_dump com $row, apareceram, melhor, os dados.

Comment: @GustavoSevero eu editei o código da resposta, o correto é `mysqli_fetch_assoc` e não `mysqli_fetch_row`, foi engano meu.

Comment: Valeu @GuilhermeNascimento, agora os dados aparecem.

Answer (score 1):

## prefiro esse exemplo

### notação Orientado à Objeto

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
 
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

### notação procedural

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Olá Danley. Prefere porque esse meio? Apesar do exemplo citado na minha resposta mostrar mysqli_data_seek, não quer dizer que é útil usa-lo comparado "LIMIT", o mysqli_data_seek pode ser usado com intervalos, por exemplo: 1, 3, 5, 7 ou até intervalos aleatórios, 2, 7, 15, 17, 18, 24, controle dele é para "navegar" baseado pelo indice da forma que a pessoa desejar. De qualquer forma concordo que para o simples, o LIMIT é o que resolve ;)

Comment: Opa Guilherme, eu concordo que o seu exemplo permite mais lógicas e, consequentemente, atender a mais requisitos; eu prefiro o exemplo dessa resposta, porque facilita para casos em que você queira pegar todos os dados com mais facilidade. Mas, principalmente, porque é mais legível para quem tá iniciando com PHP. Só mais uma forma disponível para ajudar os iniciantes.